# Mysql stored procedure split string

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, split

I write a stored procedure to split string, and insert into other form, but the result is not I want

Thanks for your help

Example I want:

Before:

```
aaa§bbb§ccc ...
```

After:

```
1:aaa
1:bbb
1:ccc
```

in this case

Before:

```
aaa§bbb§ccc ...
```

After:

```
1:aaa 
1:aaa 
1:aaa ...loop
```

I know the problem is this line, but I have no idea to write out with correct result

```
SET authorAccounts_ = SUBSTRING(authorAccounts_, CHAR_LENGTH(account));
```

and I change to this line it approaching more I want but still not

```
SET authorAccounts_ = SUBSTRING_INDEX(authorAccounts_, '§', -1);


drop procedure if exists TEST;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE searchFormId_ bigint;
  DECLARE authorAccounts_ nvarchar(2000);
  DECLARE account nvarchar(200);
  DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
          select searchFormId, authorAccounts
          from test.standardsearchform;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN c;

  REPEAT
    FETCH c INTO searchFormId_, authorAccounts_;
    IF NOT done THEN
      WHILE (CHAR_LENGTH(authorAccounts_) > 0) do
         IF (LOCATE('§', authorAccounts_) > 0) then
            SET account = SUBSTRING_INDEX(authorAccounts_,'§',1);
            SET authorAccounts_ = SUBSTRING(authorAccounts_,CHAR_LENGTH(account));
         ELSE
            SET account = authorAccounts_;
            SET authorAccounts_ = NULL;
         END IF;
         INSERT INTO test.standardsearchform_author(searchFormId, authorAccount) VALUES (searchFormId_, account);
      END WHILE;
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
  CLOSE c;
END//
delimiter ;
show PROCEDURE status;
```

Comment: Now where's that Java relevance?

Comment: sorry already remove tag